# Pumping lemma for regular language

Tags: regular-language, dfa, computation-theory, pumping-lemma

I have a little confusion in checking whether the given language is regular or not using pumping lemma.

Suppose we have to check whether:

> **L.**  The language accepting even number of `0`'s  in regular or not?

We know that it is regular because we can construct a DFA for L. But I want to prove this with pumping lemma.

Now suppose, I take a String `w= "0000"`:

Now will divide the string as `x = 0`, `y = 0`, and `z = 00`. Now on applying pumping lemma for `i = 2`, I will get the string `"00000"`, which is *not* present in my language so by pumping lemma its prove that the language is not regular. But it is accepted by DFA ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not completely clear about pumping lemma.

What pumping lemma say:

Formal definition: [**Pumping lemma for regular languages**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Formal_statement)

> Let *`L`* be a regular language.  Then there exists an integer *`p`* `≥ 1` depending only on *`L`* such that every string *`w`* in *`L`* of length at least *`p`* (*`p`* is called the `"pumping length"`) can be written as *`w`* = *`xyz`* (i.e., *`w`* can be divided into three substrings), satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. `|`*`y`*`| ≥ 1`
> 2. `|`*`xy`*`| ≤` *`p`*
> 3. for all *`i`* `≥ 0`, *`xy`<sup>`i`</sup>`z`* `∈` *`L`*

But what this statement says is that:

If a language is really a regular language then there must be *some way* to generate(*pump*) new strings from **all** *sufficiently large strings*.

1. ***Sufficiently large string*** means, a string in language that is of the length ≥ *P*.
   <sub>So it **may not** be possible to generate new string from **small** strings even if language is Regular Language</sub>
2. ***Some way*** means, if language is really a regular and our choice of `w` is correct. Then there should be *at lest one way* to break `w` in three parts `xyz` such that by repeating(pumping) `y` for any number of times we can generate new strings in the language.
   <sub>correct choice of `w` means: `w` in language and sufficiently large ≥ *P*</sub>

*note*: in second point, there may be a chance that even if you breaks `w` correctly into `xyz` according to formal definition still some new generated strings are not in language.   *As you did*.

And in this situation you are to retry with some other possible choice of `y`.

In you chosen string `w` = "**0000**" you can break `w` such that `y = 00`. And with this choice  of `y` you would always find a new generated string in in Language that is *"even number of zeros"*

<sub>One mistake you are doing in your proof that you are doing for a specific string 0000. You should proof for all `w` ≥ *P*. **So still your proof is incomplete**</sub>

Read my this answer [**IN CONTEXT OF PUMPING LEMMA FOR REGULAR LANGUAGES**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832371/to-make-sure-pumping-lemma-for-infinite-regular-languages-only/13539823#13539823)

In that answer, I have explained that *breaking `w` into `xyz` and pumping `y`* means *finding looping part and repeating looping part to generate new strings* in language.
When we proof that some language is regular; then actually we don't know where is the looping part so we try with all possible choices that satisfies pumping lemma's rule 1,2  & 3.

And Pumping lemma says that if language is regular and infinite them there must be a loop in the DFA and every sufficiently large string in language passes through looping part (according to [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)) of DFA (and hence `y` can't be null. That's rule-1 in above formal definition).

Think, loop can be at initial position or at end and so `x` and `z` can be null strings.

But actually we don't know where loop falls in DFA so we try with all possible ways.

**To proof a language is regular**: You are to proof that for ***all*** sufficiently long strings(***w***) in language there is *at-least **one** way*(***y***) to generate new strings in the language by *repeating looping part **any number*** (***i***) of times.

**To proof a language is *not* regular**:You are to find ***at least one*** sufficiently long strings (***w***) in language such that there *no choice for **any way 'y'*** so that its possible to generate new strings *with **all possible** repetition* (***i***).

```
To proof using Pumping Lemma: 
+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+
|                         | Sufficient large W in L  |     y          |    i >=0     |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+
| language is regular     | For all W (all W can use | At-least one   | For all i>=0 |  
|                         | to generate new W' in L) |                |              |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+
| language is NOT regular | Find Any W (at-least 1   | With all (Show | At-least one |   
|                         | W that can't generates   | no possible Y  | i            | 
|                         | new W' in L              | exists)        |              |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

**CAUTION:**:  The Rule always not works to proof 'Weather a Language is Regular?'

> Pumping Lemma necessary but not sufficient condition for a language to be regular. A language possible that satisfies these conditions may still be non-regular.
>   [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true)

To proof a language is regular you have some [necessary and sufficient conditions for a language to be regular.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-about-regularity-of-a-language)

Comment: [You can't prove a language is regular using the pumping lemma though.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true) There exists languages which satisfy the pumping lemma but aren't regular (though most practical languages aren't like that, it still isn't a *proof*).

Comment: @DPenner Thank you very much for this information DPenner. I should add this in my answer. And I saw through your profile you have given good answers for TOC also. Where I can find your profile link :)

Comment: Adding a link to other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174070/is-l-an-bm-nm-a-regular-or-irregular-language)

Comment: The pumping lemma can only be used to prove the 'Irregularity' of a language. The converse of the pumping lemma is not true. This can be proven using the 'Generalised Pumping lemma' for regular languages. To prove a language to be regular, you need to produce a DFA/NFA or regular expression accepting/representing the language.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is complete in its own way, I had to add a few things. I have a very playful way to exploit the pumping lemma to be able to prove that a given language is not a Regular language.
Just to have a context to talk about, let me state the lemma:

**Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages:**

> For any regular language L, there exists an integer k.
>
> Such that for all x ∈ L with |x| ≥ k, there exists u, v, w ∈ Σ∗, such
> that x = uvw, and
>
> (1) |uv| ≤ k
>
> (2) |v| ≥ 1
>
> (3) for all i ≥ 0: u(v^i)w ∈ L

The k is called the `Pumping lemma constant`. Let me come straight to the point and show you how to go about proving a language L is not regular.

Now to start the game you need two players here. One is the Reader(`R`) and the other is the Adversary(`A`).

Input: A language L

The Goal of `R`: Somehow prove the language L is not regular by some contradiction.

The Goal of `A`: Somehow be prepared enough to face the arguments of `R` and do not let him/her create a contradiction.

Now let us start the argument.

`A`: The language L is not Irregular because none could show the contradiction using pumping lemma with a certain pumping constant k. (Each language is mapped to only one integer k)

`R`: Let me assume what you say. If language L is regular then it must satisfy the conditions of the pumping lemma. So, let me choose a suitable string x ∈ L (|x| >= k), such that it helps me create a contradiction later.

`A`: Challenged by the `R`, `A` tries its best to find at least one suitable partitioning u, v and w of the string x, such that

```
x = uvw  and |uv| <= k and |v| > 0
```

`R`: With any possible partition given by `A`, wins the the argument if able to show an integer i >= 0 such that

```
u(v^i)w ∉ L
```

Because now the `R` has shown that the Language L has at least one string x which doesn't have any partition(u, v, w) such that it satisfies the pumping lemma. The contradiction happened because our assumption that L is regular is `FALSE`. Therefore the language L is proven to be not regular.

If the `R` is not able to show the above, this is not a Proof of the language being Regular. It just means that L can be a Regular or Irregular language which just happens to satisfy the pumping lemma conditions.

Always remember, the pumping lemma is `if`(`L` is regular), `then` Statements. The vice-versa is not necessarily `TRUE`. Although it might be `TRUE` in some cases.

Therefore the pumping lemma is useful only if you want to prove that a language is not regular.

(Source: [Theory of Computation(NPTEL): Prof. Somenath Biswas(IIT Kanpur)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al4AK6ruRek&list=PLbMVogVj5nJSd25WnSU144ZyGmsqjuKr3)