# Formal Language syntax

Tags: automata, formal-languages

Here is the question:

Show that:

`L = {0m1n, m > 1, n > 1, n < m }` , where m & n are superscripts

is not regular.

I am not sure what superscripts mean in this situation? Does it mean something like this:

```
0^5 = 00000 or 1^7 = 1111111
```

P.S. How can I show superscripts in SO??

Comment: Should probably be on http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MattHintzke Yes the language is not regular language you are correct. I have given/explain an [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174070/is-l-an-bm-nm-a-regular-or-irregular-language/15184740#15184740) for quite similar language. *if you have any doubt let me know*