# Tips to proof a language is not regular using Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

I am trying to prove that the following language is not regular using the pumping lemma

> L = {a<sup>i</sup> b<sup>j</sup> | i = 2j for some j ≥ 0}

I have decided to choose s = a<sup>2p</sup> b<sup>p</sup>, in this way |s| ≥ p and I can split it in three pieces xyz where for every i ≥ 0, xy<sup>i</sup>z ∈ L.

Any tips for continuing the proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Apply the lemma! you're almost done. You know that the lemma holds, so there exist such xy'z , choose i+1, show that the word is not in the language so the language is not regular.

Comment: One of the conditions of the pumping lemma says that |xy| <= p. In this case p < 2p so |y| < 2p. If I chose i = 2, the string would be xyyz. The length is |xyyz| = |xyz| + |y| < 2p+p + p. So the number of a's can't be twice the number of b's. Is it correct?

Comment: Right, just explain why the number of _a_s can't be twice as much as the number of _b_s and you're done

Comment: Here's where I'm stuck...

Comment: @colis read my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174070/is-l-an-bm-nm-a-regular-or-irregular-language/15184740#15184740) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705091/pumping-lemma-for-regular-language/14708650#14708650) In which I have explained that in pumping lemma we don't know where looping part so you need to break strings in `L` in all possible ways. And If still its a problem let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Choose s = a<sup>2p</sup> b<sup>p</sup> is right!

As said by Grijesh Chauhan we must break strings in L in all possible ways.

So you can split s in:

- x=a<sup>k</sup>
- y=a<sup>l</sup>
- z=a<sup>2p-k-l</sup> b<sup>p</sup>

where |xy|≥ 0 and |y|>0.

Taking i=2, you have xy<sup>2</sup>z:

- s = a<sup>k</sup> a<sup>l</sup>a<sup>l</sup> a<sup>2p-k-l</sup> b<sup>p</sup>

that is:

- s = a<sup>2p+l</sup> b<sup>p</sup>

Since l contains at least one 'a' (because |y|>0). You can say L is not regular