# Proving a language with a single string is regular.

Tags: dfa

Any help would be appreciated, need to figure out how to do it for an essay im typing. I have a few ideas, but I am not really sure how to put my thoughts into words.

Answer (score 1):

Check Venn-Diagram: [Any finite set is Regular set, Thing is an infinite set may or may not be regular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832371/to-make-sure-pumping-lemma-for-infinite-regular-languages-only/13539823#13539823) To proof whether an infinite set is **not** regular we use [pumping lemma property of infinite regular set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705091/pumping-lemma-for-regular-language?lq=1). But we don't need to proof a finite language/set for e.g. a language with a single string is regular as it will be regular for sure we can construct DFA and Regular expression for this language easily:

Example-1:

```
L = {a}

RE:  a

FA:  (q0) ---a---> ((qf))
```

Example-2:

```
L = {abb}

RE:  abb

FA:  (q0)---a--->(q1)---b--->(q2)--b-->((qf))
```

Comment: Upvoting because OP didn't.