# Union of two (irregular) Context Free Language results a Regular Language?

Tags: regular-language, formal-languages, context-free-language

Given L1 and L2 (irregular) context free languages - Is it possible that L1 U L2 is regular?

I know that it is possible but I just cant find an example showing that. Would love to get some assistance.

Comment: BTW, `L1 U L2` means union, not intersection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Union of two CFLs can be regular?

> Given `L1` and `L2` Context Free (but not regular) Languages, the is it possible that union of both `L1 ∪ L2` is regular?

Yes Possible!

Suppose, first language L<sub>1</sub> is:

> L<sub>1</sub> : { `anbm`  | where `n = m` }

Language L<sub>1</sub> is a CFL but not a regular. Another way of writing L<sub>1</sub> language is   `anbn`. I think this is one of the most conman example of CFL one can find in any text book of formal languages.

And Second language L<sub>2</sub> is:

> L<sub>2</sub> : { `anbm`  | where `n ≠ m` }

L<sub>2</sub> is again a CFL but not a regular. <del>Basically L<sub>2</sub> is complement language of L<sub>1</sub></del>.

Now, union of L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> is:

> L : { `anbm`  | there is no restriction over `n` and `m` values}

Language `L` = `L1 ∪ L2` is a regular language and regular expression for `L` is `a*b*`.

<del>So hint is union of complement CFLs are regular.</del>

Note: [Context-free languages are closed under union operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure_properties), so union of two CFLs are always CFL (that can be regular as class of regular languages is subset of class of CFLs), but it can't be a non-CFL e.g. CSL.

Adding on the basis of comments:

#### Intersection of two CFLs can be regular?

> Given `L1` and `L2` Context Free (but not regular) Languages, the is it possible that intersection of both `L1 ∩  L2` is regular?

Yes Possible!

Suppose, first language L<sub>1</sub> is:

> L<sub>1</sub> : { `anbm`  | where `n = m` }

And Second language L<sub>2</sub> is:

> L<sub>2</sub> : { `anbm`  | where `n <= 3 or n ≠ m` }

Language `L` = `L1 ∩ L2`  = `{ab, aabb, aaabbb}` is [a finite set and hence also a regular set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803894/finiteness-of-regular-language?lq=1).

Comment: Btw, what about intersection?

Comment: @Rouki Intersection always impose more restriction over the rules of language regeneration so intersection of two CFLs may not be even CFL.   Remember regular is less restricted language and restriction increases as from rl -> cfl -> csl.

Comment: So, is that impossible to find an example of 2 CFLs that their intersection is regular language?

Comment: @Rouki Yes possible! Suppose **L1**: `{a^nb^m where (n < 3 or m != n)}`  is a CFL (but not regular) and **L2**: `{a^nb^m where (n == m)}` is CFL (not regular) NOW,   **`L1  ∩ L2`**   = `{ab, aabb, aaabbb}` that is [a finite set hence Regular too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20818068/1673391).   `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Rouki read updated answer, l1 and l2 are not complement languages.

Comment: Sorry shouldn't CFL be less restricted than RL, because PDA is more powerful than (N/D)FA?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan , i can use your first example to prove that it is possible that L1 intersection L2 can be regular , given L1,L2=some CFL but not regular. L1={a^n b^m |n=m} and  L2={a^n b^m |n!=m} .L1 intersection L2 =phi. which is regular.right?