# Regular expression with quantity dependence

Tags: regular-language

Is it possible to create regular expression that will describe words like:

```
aabc
aaaabcbc
aaaaaabcbcbc
```

?

Words are created like each occurrence of (`bc`) on the right is connected with occurrence (`aa`) on the left.

Words below are not valid:

```
aa
bc
aaabc
aaaabc
aabcbc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it cannot be expressed in terms of regular expressions. That is because, your expression, requires a number of "aa" followed by equal number of "bc". This requires infinite memory. FA do not have infinite memory.

It can be expressed in context-free grammar.-

```
S -> aaSbc | έ     Epsilon stands for string of zero length(empty string).
```

This generates strings like -
Valid string - έ(Empty string), aabc, aaaabcbc and so on.

Read more about context free and regular grammar [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)

Comment: Correct *`'This requires memory. Regular grammars do not have memory.'`*  to `'This requires unbounded(infinite) memory, and FA contains only finite memory in-terms of states'`.

Comment: Not regular grammar but FA, grammar doesn't require memory. read [Finiteness of Regular Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803894/finiteness-of-regular-language/20818068#20818068)

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi it would be possible in non regular languages.

For example you could play with balancing groups in .NET and get something like this:

```
^(?<a>aa)+(bc(?<-a>))+(?(a)(?!))$
```

Comment: yes, but it's a programming language feature and not theoretical approach.

Comment: @Conrad Although regex != regular expression but mistake is your tags @ user3271881 just a regex.