# Proof the language is regular or not regular using Pumping lemma?

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, automata, pumping-lemma

Can any one help to figure out that L = { a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup>, m ≥ n + 2, m ≤ 3 } is regular or not using pumping lemma, It seems to be a bit difficult to prove.

I have tried to used pumping lemma and it shows that it is regular language but i am really confused that is this right or not.

Comment: That's not a programming, but a theoretical question. Also: You don't supply information on what you've already tried. Please read Stack Overflow's Help page on "how to write a good question".

Comment: @Marcus Müller i suppled some more information is this fine ?

Comment: Post this on the computer science site instead.

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried to **used pumping lemma and it shows that it is regular language** but I am really confused that is this right or not.

First note, the pumping lemma **can be used** to proof that "certain language is **not** a regular language". But we **can not use** pumping lemma to proof that "certain language **is** a regular".

Yes, the pumping lemma for regular languages describes an essential property of all regular languages, and if a languages don't satisfy the [conditions described by pumping lemma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14708650/1673391) or say don't satisfy pumping lemma property then that language is actually not a regular language, But the converse of this is not true!! &mdash- there are "languages those satisfies pumping lemma's conditions and may still be **non**-regular", means:-

> Pumping lemma is ['necessary but not sufficient condition'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) for a language to be regular.

<sub>This is something like: every engineer is math student - so if a student is engineer we can say that he knows math, but their are math students those don't know engineering. (just giving you an example to explain)</sub>

From your question, I have impression that you don't understand basically - ["what is a regular language?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730707/1673391).

Unlike pumping lemma for regular languages, we need to learn some other characteristics of regular languages - finding them in a language proofs that the language is a regular language. If you can represent a language using finite automata or/and regular expression that proofs that the language is a regular language.

Now, come to your original question:

> How to proof that language { a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup>, m ≥ n + 2, m ≤ 3 } is regular or not?

Because neither 'm' or 'n' can be negative (a string without occurrence of any symbol is possible eg. empty string<sup>1</sup>, but a string with negative occurrence of language symbols is not possible) and according to condition "m ≥ n + 2", 'm' is always greater than 'n' — so minimum value of 'm' (when 'n' is 0) is 2. From second condition "m ≤ 3", maximum value of 'm' is '3', and so 'm' can be either 2 or 3.

If you again notice fist condition: "m ≥ n + 2" for m = {2, 3} possible values for 'n' can be:

- for m = 2, n can be 0 and that makes string 'aa'.
- for m = 3, n can be 0 or 1 and that makes strings 'aaa', 'aaab'.

So, it came that the language is a finite language e. only consists of three strings.  Every finite language is a regular language, check venn diagram:

[image: See venn-diagram]

(to lean more about this read: [Finiteness of Regular Language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818068/1673391))

Regular expression for your language L = { a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup>, m ≥ n + 2, m ≤ 3 } would be **aa(a + Λ)(b + Λ)**,
hence it is proofed that language is a regular language.

<sup>1</sup> a string without occurrence of any symbol is called empty or null string in formal languages, in most of formal language books symbol Ɛ for empty string.
 Λ is empty symbol.

Answer (score -1):

we cannot use the pumping lemma for proving language is regular.To prove a language is regular  we should design DFA for that language